# Does $\nabla \phi = \nabla\times A$ have non-trivial solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-fields

As stated in the title. Is there a non-trivial solution for $n=\nabla \phi$ and $n=\nabla \times A$. With the information that $|n|=1$
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \times A = \nabla \phi
\end{eqnarray}
We can condense it to simpler expressions

\begin{eqnarray}
&\nabla^2 \phi =& \;0\\
\nabla \times(\nabla \times A) =0\Rightarrow  &\nabla^2 A=\;&\nabla (\nabla \cdot A)\\
\nabla\times \nabla^2 A = \nabla^2(\nabla\times A)=&\nabla^2 n =&\;0
\end{eqnarray}

So we have Laplace/Poisson equations. What would be the next step without digging into some representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the given conditions imply that $n$ is both divergence-free and curl-free, you are looking for a [harmonic vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_vector_field); so in particular $\Delta n = \nabla \cdot \nabla n = 0$ as you deduced. The additional condition $|n|^2 = 1$ is now very powerful: the product rule gives $$\Delta |n|^2 = 2|\nabla n|^2 +2 n \cdot \Delta n = 2|\nabla n|^2,$$ so since we know $|n|^2$ is constant we conclude that $\nabla n = 0$ everywhere; i.e. $n$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you! You are a boss. I did not think of differentiating the condition.

Comment: Is this true for curved space? Given the Levi-Civita connection I get some term with non-vanishing Christoffel-symbols.

Comment: @MichaelParis: On a Riemannian $3$-manifold your conditions instead imply that $n$ is *Hodge*-harmonic, i.e. is dual to a harmonic form. This introduces a curvature term: we find instead $|\nabla n|^2 + \mathrm{Rc}(n,n) = 0$. Thus in non-negative Ricci curvature we get the same result (all such $n$ are parallel), and in strictly positive Ricci curvature we find there are no such $n$ at all. In negative or mixed Ricci curvature I don't think we can say much. See Chapter 7 of Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry* if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you again, this is a great reference.